# Round .99 for decimal value

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

I want to round up prices(double) to nearest xx.99

For example:

`10.3  ==> 10.99`
`10    ==> 10.99`
`10.97 ==> 10.99`
`10.50 ==> 10.99`
`10.99 ==> 10.99`
`10.01 ==> 10.99`

I did `Math.Round`, `Math.Truncate`, `Math.Ceiling` but it doesn't work all case. I can convert to `string`, split and replace but I think it's not a good way.

How can I do?

Comment: what doesn't work about truncate + 0.99?

Comment: `10    ==> 10.99` is indeed an interesting way of making business ;)

Comment: What is the result of: `10.991`, is it `10.99` or `11.99`?

Comment: That's not the *closest* `.99`, that's the *next* `.99`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it is the next __*round up*__ (as opposed to `11.99` which would not be the next for presented samples)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cut the decimals away and add your .99 cents ;)

```
double value = 10.45d;
double newprice = (int)value + 0.99;
```

Comment: I'm just going to add one very minor and pedantic point.  If the price is to more than two decimal places internally then this will not work correctly if the price is, for example, 9.991.  It will give 9.99, but by the rule provided it should give 10.99.  Told you it was pedantic.

Comment: Ceiling would fail on `10.00`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @LordWilmore very valid point. I would need to ask OP whether this case is possible in the posted example. Up to now OP did not post it as examplary input ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
value = Math.Truncate(value) + 0.99M;
```

This would convert them to `decimal`.

The difference between `Math.Truncate` and casting to `(int)` is that the former preserves the type as a `double` (or `decimal`), whereas the latter converts it into an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The following

```
value = Math.Ceiling(value + 0.01m) - 0.01m;
```

It will correctly handle `value = 10 --> 10.99` and it will also result in `value = 9.991 --> 10.99` (it's not yet completely clear whether this would be your intention)

Comment: value = 9.991 --> 9.99

Comment: @user3583183 you waited quite long with this information ;)

Comment: @user3583183 well you got other correct answers in this case, I present a way for 100% up rounding ;)